# pwm value not changing

Tags: avr, pwm

I have written a pwm code for Atmega128. I am using fast pwm mode with non-inverting pulse on compare match and I need to change the OCR0 value at certain times. Yet it doesn't change. Anyone knows what is the problem here ??

```
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <avr/io.h>



uint8_t tick_1sec;



void timer1_init(void) // 1 second timer
{
    OCR1A = 15624;

    TIMSK |= (1<<OCIE1A);
    TCCR1B = (1<<WGM12);        //CTC mode
    TCCR1B |= (1<<CS12)|(0<<CS11)|(1<<CS10);    
}



ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect)  //1 second interrupt
{
    cli();
    tick_1sec = 1;
    sei();          
}



void timer0_init(void) // fast pwm with OC0 non-inverting mode
{
    TCCR0 = (1<<FOC0)|(1<<WGM01)|(1<<WGM00);
    TCCR0 |= (1<<COM01)|(0<<COM00);
    TCCR0 |= (1<<CS02)|(1<<CS01)|(1<<CS00);
    OCR0 = 63;
    TIMSK |= (1<<OCIE0);
}



int main(void)
{
    uint8_t t = 0;

    DDRB = 0xFF;

    timer0_init();      
    timer1_init();
    sei();

    while(1){

        if (tick_1sec)
        {
            tick_1sec = 0;
            t++;
            if (t == 10){
                OCR0 = 127;
            }
            else if (t == 20){
                OCR0 = 191;
            }
            else if (t == 30){
                OCR0 = 63;
                t = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please properly format your code with four spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things to check:

I recommend declaring `tick_1sec` as `volatile` to prevent the compiler of hyper-optimizing that register.

What is your clock frequency? Your ISR will deliver 1s calls only if your CPU frequency is 16MHz (==> 16.000.000 / 1024 / 15624)

You might have a LED in your hardware which you can invert from a) the `ISR` b) within the first `if ()` in `main` to see if this is ever reached.

**update**: "volatile"

The link provided by @skyrift in his comment is very worth reading.

When you use Atmel Studio, compile your code once with/without the `volatile` keyword and compare what the compiler is doing ==> Solution explorer / Output Files / *.lss ... you will see each C statement and how the compiler converts it to machine code ... an exercise worth once in a while when working with micros ...

Comment: This is almost definitely the problem - avr-gcc will wipe out most variables the are modified in an interrupt that aren't declared volatile. See part 5 here: http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&t=89843&start=all&postdays=0&postorder=asc

Comment: I took time to look at it and modified the code as you told with other parts the same. I don't know the exact reason but it worked later. Declaring Tick_1sec as volatile variable could most likely be the reason. Thank you..